# oracle odbc connection not getting all columns

Tags: ms-access, oracle10g, odbc

I have a linked table set up in Access to an Oracle 10 enterprise server.  It works great on my computer.  But I'm trying to get a co-worker set up with the same functionality, and for some reason, she can't see all the columns in the table.  It connects, refreshes, says it's linked, but not all the columns are there.  Using a different client or sql on command line we can see the whole table.  Just not in Access.  The only difference is that I'm using Oracle 9g Client and she's using Oracle 10g Express.  Any ideas?

Comment: For the linked table, don't just change connection properties then refresh.  Delete the link, then recreate fresh with the new connection information.  The reason is the Access database caches information about the ODBC link, and that information is not always reliably updated when you just refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the winner is... a table with more than 255 columns! For whatever reason, the columns that I needed for my query were available the first time I ran it, and were available to my machine in all subsequent runs.  For my co-worker, for whatever reason, 2 of the columns we needed were considered in the 255+ category.

The work-around is to use a pass-through query on the linked table in Access.  And yes, I agree - 255+ columns in a table/view is HORRID design.  Not my fault, just need the data!!

Answer (score 1):

Look into what HansUp stated about caching. There is one point I'd like to make. Ensure your co-worker is selecting from the same schema and same table. Multiple schemas (users) can have similar table names.

Example:

User a has table x with columns x,y,z

user b has table x with columns x,y

If you log in as user a and select * from x then the columns you will receive is x,y,z

if you log in as user b and select * from x then the columns you will receive is x,y

Either ensure you are logging in to the correct user or explicitdly state the schema you want in the select i.e. select * from a.x;